# Set and Test Enviornment Variables in .yaml files in Linux

Tags: linux, environment-variables, yaml

I have one abc.yml file as below which contains username and password parameters. I have stored these parameters in env variable of my linux user But when application is execting abc.yml file it's not print value of env variables. It's only print environment variables.

abc.yml:

```
type: MYSQL

host: localhost
port: 3307

username: '${user_mysql}'
password: '${pass_mysql}'
```

Linux terminal env variable check:

```
[arc@rnd-2 conn]$ echo ${user_mysql}
root
[arc@rnd-2 conn]$ echo ${pass_mysql}
notmypassword
```

Logs When abc.yml file is executed:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: (conn=375) Access denied for user '${user_mysql}'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Current charset is UTF-8. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your Java (?) program knows to lookup environment variables when it sees something of the shape `${variable}` this cannot work natively.

However you could parse the YAML file substituting in values for the variables and then have your program use the processed YAML file. A tool that will help you with this is `envsubst`

Comment: Note that passwords have a tendency to sometimes include characters like various quotes. If `pass_mysql` contains a single-quote, this string will have to undergo encoding to be included properly in the YAML document.  This is best done with a YAML-aware tool (such as `yq`).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to match the variables in the YAML file, we can use a YAML-aware tool to set the values of the top-level `username` and `password` keys.  The benefit of this is that the values would be appropriately encoded for the document.

The idea would be to modify the YAML document appropriately (or create a modified copy of it) before you try using it with whatever software reads it.

---

The following is using [the Python-based `yq` tool from Andrey Kislyuk](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), which is a wrapper around the well-known JSON processor `jq`.

Note that the password ends with a literal tab character to show that this supports arbitrary strings. I also inserted some slashes and backslashes (characters that one may possibly expect to see in passwords).

```bash
user_mysql=ruut
pass_mysql='not\/my\/password   '

yq -y \
   --arg username "$user_mysql" \
   --arg password "$pass_mysql" \
   '. += $ARGS.named' abc.yml
```

The keys don't need to be present in the input for this to work, but if they are, their values will be overwritten by the arguments passed on the command line.

Given the input document in the question, this would output the following:

```yaml
type: MYSQL
host: localhost
port: 3307
username: ruut
password: "not\\/my\\/password\t"
```

To make the change "in-place", use `yq` with its `--in-place` or `-i` option.

---

You can also do this with [the Go-based `yq` tool from Mike Farah](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/):

```bash
user_mysql=ruut
pass_mysql='not\/my\/password   '

export user_mysql pass_mysql

yq '.username = strenv(user_mysql) |
    .password = strenv(pass_mysql)' abc.yml
```

Note that the syntax for setting the values is somewhat different in this case.  I'm passing the variable via the environment and reading their values with `strenv()` inside the `yq` expression.  This means that both variables have to be exported or, in some other way, made available to the `yq` process' environment.

This `yq` utility can also do "in-place" edits if given the `-i` option.

The output, given the document in the question:

```yaml
type: MYSQL
host: localhost
port: 3307
username: 'ruut'
password: "not\\/my\\/password\t"
```